# Nested query not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

I'm experimenting with ElasticSearch. I'm having problems with querying nested objects.

My mapping:

`curl -X  GET http://localhost:9200/testt/resource/_mapping?pretty`

```
{
    "resource": {
        "properties": {
            "bib": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "IssueDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "Title": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have one indexed resource:

`curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/testt/resource/_search?pretty`

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "testt",
                "_type": "resource",
                "_id": "1234",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "SSS",
                    "bib": {
                        "Title": "XSD",
                        "IssueDate": "2012-12-19"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

`curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/testt/resource/1234?pretty`

```
{
    "_index": "testt",
    "_type": "resource",
    "_id": "1234",
    "_version": 1,
    "exists": true,
    "_source": {
        "name": "SSS",
        "bib": {
            "Title": "XSD",
            "IssueDate": "2012-12-19"
        }
    }
}
```

Yet I cannot find it using query request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "bib",
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "XSD"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Search: `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/testt/resource/_search?pretty -d '{ "query" : { "nested" : {"path" : "bib", "query" : {  "query_string" : {"query" : "XSD"} } } } }'`

```
{
    "took" : 1,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I use nested query to find my object? I'm interested in objects that have nested object `bib` that contains word `XSD`. Object `1234` clearly contains `XSD`, but I cannot find it. Can you tell me if my query is OK? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query_string` doesn't support it, but if you can parse the query yourself, you can use `multi_match` query and do something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "bib",
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "XSD",
                    "fields": ["bib.*"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A possible problem with this solution is that if you have any numeric fields in the nested document, you would need to exclude them from the list of fields. It can be achieved by adding prefixes to fields names. For example, you can rename all string fields to start with `s_`, in this case you can choose all string fields by using `"fields": ["bib.s_*"]`.

Another possible solution is to use parent's `_all` fields. You can exclude all parent's fields from the `_all` and use `_all` exclusively for the nested fields. All nested fields are included into parent's `_all` field by default.

Comment: I like your answer. How can I achieve that exclusion from `_all`? Can you provide example query with that exclusion?

Comment: It's not in the query. It's in the mapping. You need to specify `"include_in_all" : false`. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html for more information.

Comment: I will probably use "s_" prefix. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the default field in your [query_string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/testt/resource/_search -d '{ 
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "bib",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "fields" : ["Title"],
                    "query" : "XSD"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Comment: It is not answer to my question. I want to scan all fields. About `default_field` in docs: `Defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to _all.` Is it bug in ElasticSearch? I think so, as my query is not working as documentation says.

Comment: You have to explicitly set all fields then: `"query_string" : {
                    "fields" : ["Title", "Subtitle"],
                    "query" : "XSD"
                }` [Nested documents](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) don't have an own `_all` field, they use the parent document ones.

Comment: That's correct, so if you will do your search against parent's _all, you will be able to find your document `curl -XGET localhost:9200/testt/resource/_search -d '{"query": { "query_string": { "query": "XSD" } } }'`

Comment: @imotov Is it possible to search against only nested objects while not explicitly specifying all possible fields? It's crucial for my search. I want it to be elastic. Specifying all field doesn't seem to be so elastic.